# Get all records in a has_many through relation from a collection of records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given this model:

```
ModelOne
  has_many: ModelTwo
  has_many: ModelThree through: ModelTwo

ModelTwo
  belongs_to: ModelOne
  has_many: ModelThree

ModelThree
  belongs_to: ModelTwo
```

I would like to get all ModelThrees that belong to a collection of ModelOnes, like:

```
ModelOne.where(<some condition>).model_threes
```

without having to loop through all of the ModelOnes

all of the answers I've found searching for this only cover the has_many: through from a single record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working using `model_three.joins(model_two: :model_one).where(model_ones: {<the condition>})`

Answer (score 1):

I might stumble on my things here, but something like:

```
ModelThree.joins(model_two: :model_ones).where(model_two: { model_ones: { YOUR-WHERE-CLAUSE } })
```

Gonna try something out soon and then I might update!

**Update**
Changed plural form of `model_two`

Comment: console is telling me: column model_twos.model_threes does not exist

Comment: Oh, I assumed a relationship between model2 and model3 as well.
How do they look?

Comment: Can you add the other two models to your question? Just to show relations

Comment: I've added the other two models to my example to show their relation. Is there any more info about them that would be useful?

Comment: Updated my answer according to your models.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this...

```
ModelThree.joins(:model_ones).where(model_ones: { <some condition> })
```

**Update** Try adding has_many :model_ones, through: :model_twos to ModelThree

Comment: that gave me Association named 'model_ones' was not found on ModelThree

Comment: Could you add some more detail to your question showing how the associations are set up?

Comment: I've added the other two models to my example to show their relation. Is there any more info about them that would be useful?